# Why doesnt text fill its line completely?

Tags: html, css

I need to make sure height of the text is exactly same as its line. But when font-size and line-height are the same, the text is still slightly smaller then its line. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UwLm7/1/). I use text-transform: uppercase here, so there are no extra parts that stick out, like 'y'. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
<div> Some Text</div>

div {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't even understand this question.

Comment: i don't see the problem in fiddle?

Comment: There is few pixels of padding on top and bottom of the text. Im trying to get rid of those, so that text would touch bottom and top of its container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `font-size` is the maximum size for a font. In your example, `È` will fill the entire height. So if you don't plan to use accented letters, you should remove 1 or 2 pixels from the `line-height`.

This seems to give a good result:

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I posted before I saw your edit, but your answer is correct, so an upvote for you.

Comment: @TracyFu Yes I noticed you posted at the same time. Thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try reducing your line-height. When the line-height is the same as the font-size, it allows room for ascenders and descenders — like the letter 'y' as you suggested — regardless of whether you transform the text to uppercase.

http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/UwLm7/15/

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@mathieu is correct. You can cheat using the following:

```
line-height: 16px;
vertical-align: text-top;
```